# How can I recover data from /var on a broken system?

Tags: live-usb, backup

After installing KDE (and attempting to fix it by installing Gnome 3), I can no longer log in to my system as it presents me with a black screen.

This is a really bad place for me to be, because I have a bunch of data I need to recover from my installation (particularly, in `/var/www`).

Is there a way to pull this data off of my system using a Live CD before re-installing my OS?

Answer (score 6):

If you're on live media, your data and installation should be just fine. You'll need a terminal for this, so open one from the Dash menu, or by pressing the trusty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut.

1. Get a spare USB and plug it in. It should mount to `/media/ubuntu/<something>`. Make note of the mount path.
2. Type the command `blkid` and look for something with `ext*` in the name:
   Ex: `/dev/sda4: UUID="..." TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="..."`
   Make note of the partition ID (`/dev/sda4`).
3. Mount the partiton using `sudo mount <id> /mnt`, replacing `<id>` with whatever you got in step 3, in my case, `/dev/sda4`.
4. Run `cd /mnt/var`.
5. Run `sudo cp -R www/ <mountpath_from_step_1>`.

Finally, use Nautilus or `ls` to check that all of your files did actually get copied over successfully.

After it's all over and done, unmount both drives with this command:

```
sudo sync; sudo umount /mnt <mountpath_from_step_1>
```

---

Alternatively, you could have done with without live media. On the broken Ubuntu install, you could have gone to TTY4 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>), inserted a USB drive, and done this:

1. Run `lsblk` and find the USB drive's lettering (ex, `/dev/sdb1`).
2. Mount the USB drive to `/mnt` with the command: `sudo mount <step_1> /mnt`
3. Make a folder for your drive (`sudo mkdir /mnt/web-backup`)
4. Copy everything over: `sudo cp -R /var/www /mnt/web-backup`
5. Use `ls` to verify: `ls /mnt/web-backup`.
6. Unmount your USB using: `sudo sync; sudo umount /mnt`

You could also do these steps from the Recovery Shell. You can access this by pressing SHIFT while Grub boots, selecting `(advanced options)`, `(recovery mode)` for the latest kernel, and then going to the `root` option.

> **Note:** With either solution, filesystem permissons might have become a bit wonky. You're going to want to `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER <path_to_backup>` on your new system, so you can actually read the data.

Comment: Might want to make that `sudo chown -R "$USER:$USER" <path_to_backup>` to recursively chown the directory and its contents rather than just the root directory. I can't edit this myself as edits need to be at least 6 characters.

Comment: @Hitechcomputergeek Thanks for pointing that out! Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Insert an USB stick into your system and mount the partition your system is on. That is probably named sda1 (if Ubuntu is on the 1st disk otherwise sdb1 if on the 2nd disk  (etc)) or "system disk" in the launcher. The mounting can be done from nautilus or the launcher bar (it will have all partitions listed with a disk icon during the live session).

Then from Nautilus, go to `/var/www/` and copy the files you need over to the USB stick.

---

If the intention is to format the system make sure you can restore the files. Do use the "remove safely" option on the USB stick.

If you want to format the disk from this session make sure to unmount the partition.